# fopen fails to open remote url

Tags: php, fopen

I'm having some errors with `fopen` on a remote url.

I have to post some xml data to another server: since i'd wish to avoid problems with `curl` library not installed, I preferred using streams.

This is my code:

```
$url = 'http://test.mysite.com/index.php?foo=bar';
$params = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST','content' => $data));
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp  = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
     throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
}
$response = stream_get_contents($fp);
```

I tested on a local computer (Windows, PHP 5.3.8) and everthing is fine, tested live (Linux PHP 5.3.13) and is ok, then I tested locally on another pc (Windows 5.2.9).
Well in this last case, `fopen` hangs until it gets a timeout.

`allow_url_fopen` is on, there should be no problems with firewall (basically I'm calling myself: `localhost/mysite` from `localhost/mysite`)

Since a couple customers of mine reported this error I'd wish to investigate further.
Any advice?
Is there a bug or something in PHP 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your URL is not valid.
Replace:

```
$url = 'http://test.mysite.com?foo.php';
```

With:

```
$url = 'http://test.mysite.com/?foo.php';
```